# Remapping Caps-Lock to ESC doesn't deactivate the "capslocking"

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, vim, xmodmap

I'm the happy owner of an Asus ZenBook Prime UX31A-R4005P running Kubuntu 13.04.
I'm also a happy `vim` user; that means I'm lazy and don't like my hands to move more than they should.

I did remap my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to <kbd>ESC</kbd> with `xmodmap` with the following command:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```

This works on several computers, but on my ZenBook, when I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd> is sent *AND* <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> gets activated.

I could double-press the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to work around the problem, but it kind of defeats the purpose.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it another look and made some more research and I found a fix for my problem. I replaced my `xmodmap` command by a `setxkmap` one like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
setxkbmap -option caps:escape
```

I run this script as a pre-KDE-startup script.

Hope this could help somebody else.